# PHP & MySQL: Prepared statements vs function for security and coding speed

Tags: php, function, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is more of a question of 'best practice' really.

Currently coding a website back-end, and have heard the strong recommendations to use mysqli prepared statements, so have been doing that.

However, in the past I've also been told the maxim 'work smarter not harder', and as I gain the data from the HTML form with the names of each input as their field names and the processed data is in an array with the same field names, have now come across a bit of a quandary.

I have this code which I've used in the past to put data into a database from an array, updated to use mysqli->escape_string() over mysql_real_escape_string():

```
function create_insert_from_array($array, $table) {
  global $mysqli;

  $part_one = ""; $part_two = "";

  foreach ($array as $field => $input) {
    $part_one .= "`" . $mysqli->escape_string($field) . "`, ";
    $part_two .= "'" . $mysqli->escape_string($input) . "', ";
  }

  $to_ret = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (" . substr($part_one, 0, -2) . ") VALUES ("
          . substr($part_two, 0, -2) . ");";

  return $to_ret;

}
```

This allows me to put in the array and the table it's going into, and out pops a SQL statement.

My SQL Prepared Statement method for one table uses this code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO aio_sched_programmes
                          VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ?, ?, '', '', '');");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssis',
                    $end_data['name'],
                    $url_slug,
                    $end_data['long_desc'],
                    $end_data['short_desc'],
                    $end_data['image_url'],
                    $end_data['twitter'],
                    $end_data['facebook'],
                    $_SESSION['user_id'],
                    $user_profile['name']    );

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  // DO SOME STUFF AFTER CODE EXECUTION
}
```

The problem I've got to now is that with that particular prepared statement, all the fields are required. However, in the table I'm working on, not all of them are, and in my array, some will not be present, so will be overlooked when my function creates the statement. However, with the prepared statement, all the fields will need to be put into the statement with possible blanks.

It's been drilled into me (mostly from this website!) that prepared statements are more secure, but my function would save a lot of coding as I could just call that instead of having to write out the prepared statement.

So, which is better to use, or is there any way that the two can be combined to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Build the query dynamically and bind the values as needed. Prepared statements are what you should be using.

Comment: I haven't see any mysqli wrapper around but PDO. Yes, you indeed need to find a database wrapper to start learning the logic in creating a better dynamic query :)

Comment: if you work with innodb engine try creating stored procedures along with prepared statements

Comment: @Chay22 interestingly that PDO won't help in this case either.

Comment: @PeterDarmis how it will help with unknown number of parameters?

Comment: I don't get the point, what's a real problem with that. If you don't store a value into a field explicitly, it will get the default value or null as well. It is not just "empty". When you rely on specific prepared query, you can fill the missing data with `null`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, sometimes `best practice` comes with `less effort`, but all rules has exceptions. In my answer `best practice` comes with `more effort` unfortunately. Additionally parameters are set by the developer so they are never UNKNOWN in number.

Comment: Where does the array in the first function come from and how are the keys generated? `escape_string` is a good thing, `real_escape_string` is better, both are not 100% safe. Prepared statement's without any variables directly in SQL string is much better.

Comment: @chris85: I had a feeling that might be the case. Unfortunately, not necessarily knowing how many columns will have data put into them, makes it annoying.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone: the data in the array comes from a processed HTML form - each key in the array is the same name as the DB column name, but if there is an empty HTML field, it's not in this array. (I could, however, easily pass an empty field to the array!) Also, according to the PHP manual: "mysqli_escape_string — Alias of mysqli_real_escape_string()"

Comment: Very good decision of the mysqli developers! Nevertheless one should avoid including external data into SQL. If you really need to, you should take keys from a safe array matching the request data. - But to your question... Why don't you declare an array with the default data and merge the the current data array into it?

Comment: The most important thing about `create_insert_from_array()` function is that **it's prone to SQL injection.** And it prepared statements couldn't help it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use prepared statement whenever possible as soon as external data is to be involved in the statement. Since on `INSERT INTO` not mentioned fields are set to their default value, you can provide that values in PHP as well. Hold an array with the defaults together with the parameterized SQL. When you have to insert data with missing entries, merge it into the defaults.

```
<?php

function store_data(Array &$data)
{
  $default_data =
  [
    'street'  => null,
    'city'    => null,
    'credits' => 0
  ];

  $dat = array_merge($default_data, $data);
  var_dump($dat);
}

$data = 
[
  'city' => 'New York'
];
store_data($data);
?>
```

output:

```
array (size=3)
  'street' => null
  'city' => string 'New York' (length=8)
  'credits' => int 0
```

---

As you stated in the comment:

If you do not know the columns when executing a query, you should not rely on http request input. Use `` SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tablename` FROM `db`; `` to get name, type, default value and other information. Those strings are safer, but not "safe". You still need to do replacements on those strings, since they legally may contain special chars.
To get table names use `` SHOW TABLE FROM `db`; ``

Comment: Setting null value for the field and omitting the field from the query are two different actions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't say you have to set null values. You should set defaults as cedits is set to integer 0.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it since MySQL will set the missing fields automatically. The are not just "empty". Come up with a reasonable explanation if you disagree.

Comment: The problem with this particular solution in my case is that my function code works on any database table provided that the array keys match the database column names and is therefore expandable. Your solution (as above) would only work with one particular table.

I am beginning to see how flawed my original function was given how difficult is is to secure it against SQL injections!

Comment: @RichardGraham - Do you intend do build a MySQLAdmin clone? I've updated the answer to your latest information. Be aware that your current `create_insert_from_array` is seriously attackable.

Comment: Interestingly, but I never seen a PHP query builder called "MySQLAdmin".

Comment: My current project is the back-end of something, so there are a number of forms for a user to fill in to input data. So when I say that I 'don't know the columns', it is down to the fact that I have several forms that have the same basic processing, although different tables and different field names. Additionally, some of the fields are optional and therefore, after my PHP code processes the form (validation, returned warnings, etc), some of the finished array entry may be blank. I've fixed things now by just biting the bullet and not using reusable code, though would still be nice to have!

Answer (score -2):

The whole idea of prepare statements is to keep one "Database Query" template, send it once to Database and then send only the parameters. As you can find in bindParam definition (http://php.net/manual/pl/pdostatement.bindparam.php) value is passed as a reference to a variable so you can do things like that :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

// insert a row
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

(example from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

It may simplify code a bit, but imho in big applications creates even bigger mess.

Good part of prepared statements is that you create the whole query once instead of string concatenation (this is really error prone). One of the most common issues is when you concatenate string and variable is empty, then you'll get something like :

```
INSERT INTO table ...... VALUES (1, 12, , 'ABC');
```

And MySQL will give an syntax error (because of `,,`). It's pretty common issue when people do the query string concatenation.

Another awesome feature is that when you're binding parameters to the query you can specify the parameter type (I highly recommend using it). With this approach you can easily support any database, because for example if column `position` has type `int` and you push a string :

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (id, position) VALUES (1, '1');
```

MySQL will execute the command, PostgreSQL will fail because you're trying to assign `string` to integer. Specifying type solves also all SQL inject issues. I see that in first example you're escaping string (very good) but it's easy to forget about this small thing. And what if someone passed you already escaped string ??

IMHO the best way how to create database queries is to 
 - use prepared statements (better performance), less error prone
 - type every query parameter

Nice code example (stolen from php.net website):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

And a small hint about your code, instead of creating string using `foreach` and then removing last parameters thing about `join()` function.

Comment: I am using prepared statements, and know the positives of doing them! I just had some code from a previous project (before I started using prepared statements - actually, I was still using 'mysql' not 'mysqli' in PHP at that point!) that would've been useful.

My problem was mainly to do with not knowing necessarily how many or which columns I am entering data into. Some will be blank as it depends on the array.

I thought that `join()` / `implode()` only worked on the array values and not the keys as well (which my function uses too).

Comment: You say you don't know how many/or which columns you're entering data into, I'm not sure but it might mean that NoSQL DB would be better solution. Anyway, if you create db query dynamically still you have to write an SQL query. Prepared statements and named parameters will help you tackling this problem (you don't have to worry about data, you just have to create proper SQL query), then allow PDO/msqli to handle data validation. If you miss some parameters it will tell you which one are missing. Plus it is much easier to maintain few method calls than a huge string concatenation.

Comment: This essentially doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: sorry, pressed enter by mistake in the middle of sentence

Comment: @PolishDeveloper, true, but my function is writing the SQL query.

My array is: `[prog_id] => 41,
    [week] => 22,
    [day] => 6,
    [start_time] => 14:20:00,
    [end_time] => 20:19:59,
    [broad_type] => 3`

Each of those keys is the same as the MySQL column name. My function loops through the array, creating `prog_id, week, day, start_time, end_time, broad_type` for `$part_one` and `'41', '22', '6', '14:20:00', '20:19:59', '3'` as `$part_two`, combining them to the full SQL statement.

All a moot point as I've realised I'll just have to do the full prepared statement anyway!

Comment: @RichardGraham - to be honest I don't remember the last time when I wrote the whole MySQL query by myself (other than a simple check on production db). Creating query string is a difficult task. Instead of prepared statements you can use QueryBuilders that will do the job for you (you just have to specify table, and what you want to read/push). QueryBuilder will do type checking,data escaping and allow you to use any database (sqlite,mysql,postgres,oracle). MySQLI/PDO prepared statements will help you with creating the query and handle data validation. IMHO it's a good thing.

Comment: Anyway, on this stage I wouldn't think about performance. Write code for humans not machines and pick the solution you feel the best, the solution that it is easy to maintain. IMHO prepared statements and query building is much better way than manual string concatenation.

Comment: In essence, this answer is just a general purpose rant on prepared statements, which fails to answer the question asked. Besides, it's flawed by itself. For example, the OP is working not with postgre but with mysql, and the latter happily allows a quoted number in the query. While speaking of performance one must remember that repeated inserts happen extremely rare, which makes performance gain is either negligible or even negative.

Comment: And I just saw your code. For the `$part_two` you're passing ids as a strings (example: `'41', '22, '6' ...`). That is not fully correct (although MySQL will accept it). If you go with `bindParam('prog_id', $prog_id, PDO::PARAM_INT)` it will pass it as a number (example: `41, 22, 6, '14:20:20'...`).

Comment: @YourCommonSense with prepared statements approach and binding params it is much easier to handle incorrect data. If you concatenate strings by yourself it's easy to make errors. If something is missing PDO/MySQLi will complain whats wrong (with named arguments) and it's much easier to find and fix it, if you create big query by yourself then it might take a while to find out that you have `,,` or `''` somewhere in your query.

Comment: Again you are confusing matters. No prepared statement will save you from `,,` case. Besides, neither PDO's not mysqli's error messages on prepared statements are helpful or make any use of named arguments.

Comment: It's not about confusion, it's more what do we have in PHP, and I was more talking about PDO and `prepare` function than `mysql_prepare` which in fact creates only prepared statement. Good catch @YourCommonSense.